# Вложенные блоки не заполняют всю высоту родителя без явного указания height

Tags: css, css3

Если задать блоку `min-height` вместо явного `height`, то в `IE` внутренние блоки не будут заполнять его по высоте полностью; в других браузерах все нормально. Есть какой-нибудь способ исправить такое поведение в `IE`?

https://jsfiddle.net/94ob8xmy/3/

Comment: для ie есть хуки - которые пишутся специлально для ie 10-11

Comment: @MaximLensky, только таким способом?

Comment: ну допустим если написать height то применится это везде же да ? а если написать только для ie то применится только в ie верно ? ie вообще самый тупой браузер и стили там совсем другие но если хотите получить ответ выкладывайте свой код ...я не совсем понимаю о чём речь

Comment: @MaximLensky, я выложил код, иллюстрирующий проблему, на jsfiddle.

Comment: вот видите - совсем  другая информация в песчнице нежели в вопросе: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex это говорит о том что IE плохо понимает flexbox

Answer (score 3):

Вы [не можете](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) использовать flexbox, если вам требуется поддержка IE. Только 10 и 11 версии частично поддерживают это свойство, а 6-9 не поддерживают вообще. Поэтому вам придется использовать другие стили. Как вариант (работает в IE9 и выше, ниже - нужно проверять):

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 300px;  
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.child {
  min-height: 300px;  
  border: 1px dotted #ff0000;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.child_1 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.child_2 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "child child_1">Text 1</div>
  <div class = "child child_2">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

Чтобы применимть эти стили только к IE, воспользуйтесь хуками. Они зависят от того, какие именно версии IE вам нужно поддерживать. Детальнее об этом [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20541859/11907753).

Comment: @MaximLensky, вопрос был о том, как исправить такое поведение. Про обязательность использования flex в вопросе не упомянуто.

Comment: я не спорю но плюсик поставлю всё равно хоть согласен я хоть нет